# is there a way to separate the duplicated items in a list into another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
physics = list()
chemistry = list()
history = list()
geography = list()
comSci = list()
notAllocated = list()
subjects = ['physics', 'chemistry', 'history', 'geography', 'comsci']
nameVar = None
subjectVar = None

def SubjectChosen(subjectVar, nameVar):
    if subjectVar.lower() == subjects[0]:
        physics.append(nameVar)
    elif subjectVar.lower() == subjects[1]:
        chemistry.append(nameVar)
    elif subjectVar.lower() == subjects[2]:
        history.append(nameVar)
    elif subjectVar.lower() == subjects[3]:
        geography.append(nameVar)
    elif subjectVar.lower() == subjects[4]:
        comSci.append(nameVar)

def SubNos(list):
    if len(list) < 10:
        print("this group is under subscribed")
        notAllocated.append(list)

    elif len(list) > 20:
        print("this group is over subscribed")
        if 40 >= len(list) >= 30:
            print("group 1:", list[0:21])
            print("group 2:", list[21:])
        elif 30 > len(list) > 20:
            print("group:", list[:21])
            notAllocated.append(list[21:])
        elif len(list) > 40:
            print("group 1:", list[0:21])
            print("group 2:", list[21:41])
            notAllocated.append(list[41:])



for i in range(61):
    nameVar = input("enter the students name: ")
    subjectVar = input("enter the subject chosen: ")

    while subjectVar not in subjects:
        try:
            subjectVar = input("enter a valid subject: ")
        except:
            print("enter a valid subject!")

    SubjectChosen(subjectVar, nameVar)

    subjectVar = input("enter the second subject chosen: ")

    while subjectVar not in subjects:
        try:
            subjectVar = input("enter a valid subject: ")
        except:
            print("enter a valid subject!")

    SubjectChosen(subjectVar, nameVar)


print("physics:", len(physics), 'people', physics)
SubNos(physics)

print("chemistry:", len(chemistry), 'people', chemistry)
SubNos(chemistry)

print("history:", len(history), 'people', history)
SubNos(history)

print("geography:", len(geography), 'people', geography)
SubNos(geography)

print("comSci:", len(comSci), 'people', comSci)
SubNos(comSci)

print(notAllocated, "arent allocated")
```

basically, I'm taking an input of 2 subjects per person and then running the lists through specifications and if they are out of bounds the subject doesn't get allocated, is there a way to use the duped names in the

```
notAllocated()
```

list and move those to another list so the ones with only one subject are separated from those with no subjects?

Comment: add sample input and expected output

Comment: Instead of all these different list variables, why not a single dictionary keyed by the subjects?

Comment: @JohnColeman its a requirement of the question to use only one dimensional arrays